# Tensorflow: Picking an optimal model from a training session

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

When training a deep learning network (say with TensorFlow or similar), it is common to train for a fixed set of samples and hope the results get better with longer training.  But this assumes monotonically increasing accuracy, which as shown below, is clearly not true.  As shown below, stopping at "2.0" would have had ten percentage points better accuracy.  Is there any common procedure for picking off better models and saving them. 
 In other words a Peak-Detection routine.  Perhaps,  keeping track of the test-accuracy throughout the training session and saving off the model (checkpoint?) whenever the accuracy was higher than a previous value.
Questions:

1. What is best practice for picking off the best model?
2. Does TF have an methods for this?
3. Is there merit to continuing to train even longer (maybe a lot longer), on the theory that the optimizer will eventually find a better solution.
4. Is a checkpoint the best save method?

Thanks.
[image: Original graph]

**EDIT:** Thanks to the recommendations from @Wontonimo, the improved accuracy results are shown below.  The following changes were made:

- reduce the learning rate in the Adam optimizer from 0.003 to 0.001
- add two additional dropout layers (prob=0.5)
- shuffle-select training frames from the full data set (instead of sequence-selecting)
- increase training iterations by 50%.

With these changes it seems that it would be advantageous to continue training even further.  And possibly add more regularization.

[image: New training graph]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This highlights 2 common problems in machine learning

- **1 : learning rate instability**
- **2 : overly optimistic**

**learning rate instability**
First let's talk about learning rate instability.  The error rate of your graph shows improvement then suddenly, as if the NN saw some piece of data that voided all of its previous experience, it had its full understanding of the problem blown.  If we think in terms of training an animal or a person, this could happen if we make the next training sessions results too important instead of taking the long view.  People in the industry talk about **learning rate decay**, which is similar to saying "once you have basic understanding, make small changes to your mental model".

Specifically, consider decreasing your learning rate by 1/2 or a 1/3rd.  Additionally try using a more robust learning algorithm.  If you are using gradient descent, then try using a momentum based gradient descent.  Lastly, decrease your learning rate by 1/2 or 1/3 again if you see these wild swings down in test accuracy.  If you are not using a regularizer like dropout in your last layer, that can also help to keep your training results closely related to your test results so that you do not overfit.

**overly optimistic**
You mentioned that you would like to stop training when you have good results.  You are ignoring that your model does not actually converge.  Ignoring the poor results is being overly optimistic about the model.

I think your model shows great promise if it is able to get to **0.8**.  Small changes like monumentum and dropout will stabilize your results.

**Updated : Minibatch**
After much review of your old graph and your new graph and taking into consideration comments, it appears that you could decrease the noise **considerably** by using a larger **minibatch**.  Consider increasing your batch size by x10.  Your graph very much looks like SGD, or a batch size small enough to have similar results.  It is important to average your loss function across the batch results before sending it to Adam to gain the benefit.  If you do this you may have to run up to x10 the number of epochs but you will see much smoother graphs.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent comment.  In our case we are using the Adam optimizer, which, I believe, is implements learning rate decay automatically.  But clearly it is not enough.  Regarding regularization, we are using one dropout layer, but your comments suggest a second would not be a bad thing.

Comment: However, the original question still seems useful.  Should I infer that a well designed training system is monotonic and doesn't need peak-detection?

Comment: I would say yes, a well designed system **tends** towards monotonic-ish behavior.  However, no need to burn CPU on unnecessary work, so something that detects a plateau would be useful to quit and queue your next job.

Comment: @Hephaestus - this this answered your questions, please mark it as the **accepted** solution.

Comment: The difficulty is that my question still stands.  Even in the second graph there is a 5-10 percentage point variation in the red trace from iteration to iteration at the end.  That's alot to give up depending on when the training loop happens to end.  I'm hoping to get some recommendations on ways to pick the best result regardless of when the loop end.  Do you have some ideas?  Does TF have some methods, or does one just keep writing checkpoints whenever the accuracy gets a little higher?

Comment: I'm assuming that each point on your graph isn't 1 epoch, but somewhere part way through 1 epoch, so there will be a variation. Let's say that you took a weighted average of recent test accuracies (using rolling or lambda averages) over 1 or 0.5 epochs, we could clearly see a trend of improvement (even with the spikes), but starting at epoch 2.5 the average doesn't really change (and may go up).  That is your early stop criteria.  Save your model at each epoch (or 0.5) and use the model with the lowest **test accuracy**.

Comment: Similarly, that is a good detection point to reduce your learning rate if you are using Gradient Descent, but you are using **Adam** which has a mechanism to auto adjust.  It looks like after epoch 2.0 your network is overfitting.  That's evident from the separation.  When your training is able to continue to improve training stats but test stats flatline, your network is at its limit and further training is just overfitting, which goes back to my previous statement.  Once an epoch look for **test accuracy** or **test loss** to flatline or revert as an indication to stop

Answer (score 0):

I think that in this scenario it is better to approach the problem from a different angle probably selecting another model. To me this accuracy graph looks very noisy are really random.